# Stretching of a set of numbers to align to a reference

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, linear-programming

I am trying to align an ordered set of n real, strictly positive numbers

$$Q = {q_{1},q_{2},..., q_{n}}$$

to a reference set of the same size and with the same properties

$$R = {r_{1},r_{2},..., r_{n}}$$

I am looking for an analytical solution to find the resulting set

$$S = {s_{1},s_{2},..., s_{n}}$$

that minimizes the differences between S and R

$$F(S)=\sum_1^n|r_{i}-s_{i}|$$

$$argmin_S F(S)$$

but preventing the length of each "segment" $s_{n}s_{n+1}$ from stretching too much from the original length $q_{n}q_{n+1}$, keeping the ratio between two numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

$$\alpha \le {s_{n+1} - s_{n}\over q_{n+1} - q_{n}} \le \beta $$

with $0\lt\alpha \le 1$  and $\beta \ge 1$ that are input data of the problem.

In case there is not an analytical solution, I would like to find a numerical solution with a complexity that is not exponential. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "minimizing the difference between $S$ and $R$" instead? The equation for $F(S)$ probably also needs to refer to $r_i$ instead of $q_i$.

Comment: hope it's understandable though. if it's lots of work to solve it, I'd like some pointers to solve such problems and I will try to answer the solution myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear programming problem. Introduce $n$ variables $z_i$ with linear constraints
$$\begin{align}
z_i &\ge r_i-s_i, \\
z_i &\ge -(r_i-s_i).
\end{align}$$
For fixed $r_i$ and $s_i$, we have $\min z_i = \lvert r_i-s_i \rvert$. (It's instructive to visualize the two-dimensional feasible set for just $z_1$ and $s_1$.) So you can express your problem as minimizing the linear objective
$$f(s_1,\ldots,s_n,z_1,\ldots,z_n) = z_1 + \cdots + z_n$$
subject to the linear constraints
$$\begin{align}
s_{n+1} - s_{n} &\ge \alpha(q_{n+1} - q_{n}),\\
s_{n+1} - s_{n} &\le \beta(q_{n+1} - q_{n}),\\
z_i &\ge r_i-s_i, \\
z_i &\ge -(r_i-s_i).
\end{align}$$

Comment: it it right that the first two formulas are identical? I read a bit about linear programming and get back to this, because I have no clue on how to use it to write my routine!

Comment: @Alex: They're not identical. I rewrote them anyway to make it more obvious.

Comment: @Alex: There is [a lot of software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages) out there for solving linear programming problems. You just put your numbers into the solver and it gives you the answer. I wouldn't recommend writing your own code to solve it yourself (just like you wouldn't write your own `sqrt`).

Comment: sorry i can't upvote!

Comment: got it! glpk rocks

Comment: I am still having problems with the formulation

Comment: @Alex That's not a very informative comment.